# Is there a way to have a macro run automatically IF a cell changes to a certain value (i.e. if greater than X)?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm creating a calculator and have to compare dates as part of the tool. I'm trying to get the macro to run automatically  AND check if the days between the dates is greater than 185 days. When researching and testing out different options, I haven't been successful. It can run if I create a button but need it to run automatically (if days between dates are greater than 185 days). Cell C10 is the cell that calculates the number of days between the two dates the user provides.

This is my original code, but changed it so that it would be more automatic:

```
Sub Duration_Error()
  
  If Range("C10") > 185 Then
    MsgBox "Based on the dates provided, this greater than 185 days .Please contact XYZ.", vbRetryCancel + vbExclamation, Title:="Duration Error"
Else
    Exit Sub

End If
    
End Sub
```

The below is what I tried but when I test it with the dates, nothing happens. When I try running it from VBA I know get the Macros dialog box to appear - so I know I'm doing something **very** wrong.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Address = "$C$10" And "$C$10" > 185 Then
  MsgBox "Based on the dates provided, this greater than 185 days .Please contact XYZ.", vbRetryCancel + vbExclamation, Title:="Duration Error"
Else
    Exit Sub

End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Calculations don’t trigger the Change event - you need worksheet_calculate for this.

Comment: What is the formula in `C10`? If it's something like `C9-C8`, where the dates are manually entered (not formulas), you could use these cells instead.

Comment: @VBasic2008 - yes, that's correct. But I need it to run and only show the message only if the number of days is greater than 185 days. would it need to be a nested if in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### A Worksheet Change: Sum of Two Cells Override

- It is assumed that cells `C8` and `C9` are manually populated.
- In `C10` is a formula that uses these two cells to return a numeric value.
- Show a message if the value in `C10` is greater than `185`.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Const MSG_PROMPT As String = "Based on the dates provided, " _
        & "the difference is greater than 185 days. Please contact XYZ."
    Const MSG_TITLE As String = "Duration Error"
    Const TRIGGER_RANGE As String = "C8,C9" ' adjust!
    Const CHECK_CELL As String = "C10"
    Const MAX_DAYS As Long = 185
    
    If Intersect(Me.Range(TRIGGER_RANGE), Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    With Me.Range(CHECK_CELL)
        If Not IsNumeric(.Value) Then Exit Sub
        If .Value <= MAX_DAYS Then Exit Sub
    End With
    
    MsgBox MSG_PROMPT, vbExclamation, MSG_TITLE
    
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you so much for your guidance. I've tried the code you've shared above (with the needed adjusts) but the macro is not auto running. I entered the dates (that were more than 185 days) and nothing happens. I also tried running it from Visual Basic but the Macros dialogue box comes up. Do I need to add anything to make .value reference C10? My question may be silly but still a newbie with macros.

Comment: You have to copy this code to the correct place. In Excel, right-click the correct tab and select `View Code`. The window that opens is the correct place. Remove any other instances you may have copied. This is an event code and it runs automatically: as soon as you (manually) change `C8` or `C9`, the code checks if `C10` is greater than 185 and acts accordingly.

Comment: Awesome! I've moved the code and it is working as intended! Thank you so much!